# How to ignore the _site.yml file when generating a html page with a rmd file?

Tags: r, r-markdown

When using [rmarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) to generate a website, a html file is generated with the help of a _site.yml file in the some folder. However sometimes, I want use a rmd file in the same folder to generate pdf, or flexdashboard files. It seems that when the _site.yml file is present, even when another output is specified in the header in the rmd file, an html file is generated.

I would like to know if there is a way to ignore the _site.yml file.

Comment: You can specify the output you desire in the preamble, no? And if im not mistaken in Rstudio you can select your desired output.

Comment: yes. but if the preamble is empty, then the information in _site.yml will be used. Since in my _site.yml, the specific output is html, I want to mask it with another in the preamble, but I cannot achieve. Maybe it is not possible ?

Comment: Well you can add a preamble that renders it as a pdf and your yml file will override that. When you dont want it to override that simply delete the call to the yml file in your rmd file and knit. Alternatively, simply click the the knit button in Rstudio and a dropdown menu should appear with the options of html, pdf, or word.

Comment: It seems that the yml file will override, and that is the problem. I would like to have something to override the yml file. In fact, for almost rmd files, it is OK, they are to be rendered into the website. However, I have some rmd to be generated into pdf or flexdashboard. So I don't want to change yml.

Comment: Move them to a different folder from you project folder.